# How to automate variable replacement in R?

Tags: r, loops, automation

I am using the `scPDSI` package in R to generate drought indexes for about 8 thousand sites. I have monthly data from 1994 to 2018. Each one of my sites has its own column in the csv file. For example, for my first site, I have precipitation (`P1`) and potential evaporation (`PE1`). With the `scPDSI` package, I simply write the following:

```
Index <- pdsi(Drought$P1, Drought$PE1, start = 1994, end = 2018, sc=TRUE)
```

and it calculates the drought index for my first site.

How do I make R generate the index for each site without me having to replace `P1` (and `PE1`) for `P2` (resp. `PE2`) and then `P3` (`PE3`), so on and so forth manually? Is this even possible?

Comment: The file has 8K columns? Can you post a small subset of it, for instance, the output of `dput(Drought[1:20, 1:8])`?

Comment: The file has 16K columns because each site has a precipitation value (P) and a potential evaporation value (PE). My first column is "year", the next one is "month", the next one is "P1", the next one is "PE1", then "P2", then "PE2"... and so on.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear and for the data, but it's (much) better if you edit the question with the data, please. Given your description of the data set, my comment would select columns year and month, then 3 pairs of cols for `P*`, `PE*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the code below solves the question's problem. Untested, since there are no data.

```
library(scPDSI)

fun <- function(x, y, data, start, end, sc){
  X <- data[[x]]
  Y <- data[[y]]
  pdsi(X, Y, start = start, end = end, sc = sc)
}

other_args_list <- list(
  data = Drought,
  start = 1994, 
  end = 2018, 
  sc = TRUE
)

Pcols <- grep("^P\\d+$", names(Drought), value = TRUE)
PEcols <- grep("^PE\\d+$", names(Drought), value = TRUE)

Index_vec <- mapply(fun, Pcols, PEcols, MoreArgs = other_args_list)
```

Comment: This helped! I just had to remove data=data part from within the pdsi function line. The pdsi function was not able to recognize it. Thanks!

Comment: @SvenBrandt Thanks for the feedback. And there was no need for `data = data` since the function creates `X` and `Y` from the function's data argument. Code corrected.